# Still got null value for a bean instance even add @service decorator

Tags: java, spring

I got null exception for the bean CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.
In my entire application only this class implement CustomUserDetailsService.
However, Spring seems still not able to load the bean.

Any idea?

## auth.java

```
CustomUserDetailsService userService = (CustomUserDetailsService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl");
```

## CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;


    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {  
      ........
}
```

## Entry class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class XprojApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(XprojApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public SpringApplicationContext springApplicationContext()
        {
            return new SpringApplicationContext();
        }


        @Bean(name="AppProperties")
        public AppProperties getAppProperties()
        {
            return new AppProperties();
        }


    }
```

## Folder structure

```
    ./
    ├── SpringApplicationContext.java
    ├── XprojApplication.java
    ├── dto
    │   ├── Metadata.java
    │   ├── QueryFilter.java
    │   ├── RealEstateTransaction.java
    │   ├── TransactionDTO.java
    │   └── UserDto.java
    ├── exceptions
    │   └── UserServiceException.java
    ├── model
    │   ├── CustomUserDetails.java
    │   ├── RoleEntity.java
    │   └── UserEntity.java
    ├── repository
    │   ├── TransactionJpaRepo.java
    │   └── UsersRepository.java
    ├── request
    │   ├── LoginRequestModel.java
    │   ├── UserDetailsRequestModel.java
    │   └── UserLoginRequestModel.java
    ├── resource
    │   ├── AppController.java
    │   ├── AuthenticationController.java
    │   └── UserController.java
    ├── response
    │   └── UserRest.java
    ├── security
    │   ├── AppProperties.java
    │   ├── AuthenticationFilter.java
    │   ├── AuthorizationFilter.java
    │   ├── SecurityConstants.java
    │   └── WebSecurityConfiguration.java
    └── service
        ├── CustomUserDetailsService.java
        ├── CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.java
        ├── RealEstateTransactionService.java
        └── RealEstateTransactionServiceImpl.java
```

Comment: Can you please add the main class, Your project structure. Hope you have not added the component scan annotation in your main class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using lower case 'c' => "customUserDetailsServiceImpl" i.e using the convention over configuration spring defaults

```
CustomUserDetailsService userService = (CustomUserDetailsService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("customUserDetailsServiceImpl");
```

**Or**

Be explicit in naming the bean

```
@Service("customUserDetailsServiceImplBean")
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {
...
}

CustomUserDetailsService userService = (CustomUserDetailsService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("customUserDetailsServiceImplBean");
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much details on how is your context configuraed exactly and what exactly is `SpringApplicationContext` here, so I'll provide only general point to consider here:

1. Spring might not scan the package where the `CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl` resides.
   When spring starts the application context it should know somehow where you put the beans (in which directories). Its specified when you load the spring (or if you're using spring 
   boot it has some pre-defined rules for this, but I don't see that you use spring boot). 
   Then it scans the packages and tries to resolve the beans from there. If the package is not among the packages to be scanned, obviously the bean won't be created.
2. The package is scanned however the bean `CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl` cannot be created because one of its own dependencies is not resolved. In this case the application context startup process will fail and you'll see a lot of messages in the log.
3. The bean is loaded and the application context is started however when you refer it by:`CustomUserDetailsService userService =(CustomUserDetailsService)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl");` then something goes wrong and you get null. In this case, the name (and the method call is actually calling bean by name) is wrong. I suggest you using the get bean by id functionality instead (it will avoid the ugly casting by the way):

   ```
   CustomUserDetailsService userService = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(CustomUserDetailsService.class);
   ```